# How do I mention the author of the command in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

I'm trying to make the command also mention the person who wrote the command, how do I add it to the current command:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
token = "" #bot token here
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix= "!")
@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send('pong')
```

I have tried to add this code:

```
@client.command()
async def command(ctx):
    author = ctx.message.author
```

.. but it hasn't worked for me while making it print the author as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to add it to a command, ctx.author.mention should do the job

```
@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'pong {ctx.author.mention}')
```